# Issue with File Upload in Django

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a Django project where users can upload images. I've followed the Django documentation on file uploads, but I'm encountering an issue.
I'm not receiving any error messages, but the uploaded file is not being saved to the expected location.I've checked the Django documentation on file uploads, and I've also reviewed similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find a solution to my specific issue.
What could be causing the file not to be saved to the specified directory?

Comment: Is the image not being saved at all, or just not to the expected place? Did you try doing a search in Finder to see if the image exists anywhere on the device, and if so where?